# Segment tree memory

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

I have seen many implementations of segment trees that use O(4*N) memory. Is there anyway for a segment tree to use exactly 2*N-1 memory? I cannot find any implementation that does this. Even if they talk about the space complexity being actually 2*N-1 they still allocate 4*N.

EDIT: What I mean is that for an array of n numbers you use an array of 2n-1 numbers for a segment tree. Every implementation uses an array of 2*(next power of 2 greater than n).

I know that the O notation omits constants but for a very large n it would matter if it is 2*N-1 or 4*N, thus the reason I asked this question.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), O(4*N) = O(2*N-1) = O(N). Any standard implementation of segment tree uses linear memory.

Coming to your question, consider an array `a[0...n-1]` as input. Consider `n = 10`. When you construct the segment tree, it will look something like following:

[image: Segment Tree]

Number of nodes used for construction = 2*n - 1 = 19. Thus, theoretically, only 19 nodes are required!

But, we are implementing the segment tree using `array` data structure. Here, each node will correspond to some index in `array`. In segment tree, for node indexed `x`, left-child index = `2*x`, right-child index= `2*x+1`.

So, if I start with one-indexed array , index of `[0, 9] = 1, [5] = 24, [6] = 25`. So, you atleast need index till `25` in this case. In worst case, you will need index of `31` in case of fully grown segment tree `(n=16)`.

Thus, we maintain the `array` with size `2*(next power of 2 >= n)`

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically add nodes to the tree. Then the nodes that you are not using will just not exist and won't waste memory.

Answer (score 1):

O(4*N) = O(2*N) = O(N) because the O-notation does abstract from constant factors.

[wikipedia Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

So what do you mean by "use exactly 2*N-1 memory"? Du you mean 2*N-1 bytes? If you mean O(2*N-1) than this is the same as O(4*N), O(2*N) and O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Most people are familiar with implementing the safe **4N** allocated memory which happens to be the upper bound for building a segment tree on an array of size **N** or the OOP version. For some idea behind this, read [here](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html). It's a very good source and has a lot of information packed on segment trees.

Now, coming to the **2N** memory usage. Take a look [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18051), [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/1256) and also:

> Memory efficient implementation (from [here](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html))

> Most people use the implementation from the previous section. If you look at the array t you can see that it follows the numbering of the tree nodes in the order of a BFS traversal (level-order traversal). Using this traversal the children of vertex v are 2v and 2v+1 respectively. However if n is not a power of two, this method will skip some indices and leave some parts of the array t unused. The memory consumption is limited by 4n, even though a Segment Tree of an array of n elements requires only 2n−1 vertices.
> However it can be reduced. We renumber the vertices of the tree in the order of an Euler tour traversal (pre-order traversal), and we write all these vertices next to each other.

> Lets look at a vertex at index v, and let him be responsible for the segment [l,r], and let mid=l+r2. It is obvious that the left child will have the index v+1. The left child is responsible for the segment [l,mid], i.e. in total there will be 2∗(mid−l+1)−1 vertices in the left child's subtree. Thus we can compute the index of the right child of v. The index will be v+2∗(mid−l+1). By this numbering we achieve a reduction of the necessary memory to 2n.